# what kind of message/dialog box is this in html, css?

Tags: html, css

Is this kind of alert box?

[image]

[image]

I googling it but haven't yet seen any answer. TIA

Comment: it is a kind of tool tip. you can check this: https://popper.js.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its called tooltip, In popular framework like bootstrap you can use it like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!" data-placement="right">Hover over me</a>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not an alert box. It is a tooltip from bootstrap.

see the documentation here : [[Bootstrap Tooltip documentation][1](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/)